# Large JSON response takes a lot of time in GoFiber

Tags: json, rest, go, go-fiber

We have a json that is of 40kb, it takes around 200ms. If just reduced three fields in the json, the size reduced to 36kb but the response drops to 125ms on avg. We used json:"-" tags in the fields that we do not want to send. We are sending using

```
ctx.Status(fiber.StatusOK).JSON(model.GetEventListResponse{
        Events:   events,
        NextPage: nextPage,
})


type GetEventListResponse struct {
    NextPage string  `json:"next_page"`
    Events   []Event `json:"events"`
}

type Event struct {
    EventID           int64         `json:"event_id"`
    Currency          int           `json:"currency"`
    EventName         string        `json:"event_name"`
    Country           string        `json:"country"`
    Place             string        `json:"place"`
    EventFrom         time.Time     `json:"event_from"`
    MainEventStart    time.Time     `json:"main_event_start"`
    TotalParticipants int64         `json:"total_participants"`
    TotalPool         float64       `json:"total_pool"`
    Laps              int           `json:"laps"`
    TotalDistance     float64       `json:"total_distance"`
    SingleLapDistance float64       `json:"single_lap_distance"`
    LapRecordTime     time.Duration `json:"lap_record_time"`
    LapRecordBy       string        `json:"lap_record_by"`
    IsActive          bool          `json:"-"`
    IsComplete        bool          `json:"-"`
    Games             []int64       `json:"-"`
}
```

The number of events are 100.

JSON Response:-

```
{
    "next_page": "Pw0hLnA......................KK1f8bc9LIY=",
    "events": [
        {
            "event_id": 202312181540001,
            "currency": 64,
            "event_name": "Event39",
            "country": "Country39",
            "place": "Place39",
            "event_from": "2023-12-12T15:09:02.619Z",
            "main_event_start": "2023-12-12T15:09:02.619Z",
            "total_participants": 292,
            "total_pool": 1676.4006608884679,
            "laps": 28,
            "total_distance": 876.2850461295575,
            "single_lap_distance": 8.119311404702122,
            "lap_record_time": 54542000000000,
            "lap_record_by": "Racer39"
        },....}
}
```

Comment: We have even compression provided by go fiber

Comment: What takes 200ms? Processing the json? marshaling it?

Comment: The whole request

Comment: If we put  json:"-" in all the fields except 3, the whole request will take only 72 ms

Comment: How gofiber sends the data is taking the significant time including marshalling and everything.

Comment: Measure where the bottleneck is. Size of the message is immeterial.

Comment: the last step ctx.Status(fiber.StatusOK).JSON(model.GetEventListResponse{
        Events:   events,
        NextPage: nextPage,
})

Comment: This is taking a lot of time. When the fields are reduced, it is very faster. We tried different json encoder but got no luck

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using https://github.com/bytedance/sonic

I think you need to write benchmark tests that compare the performance of data marshaling with different encoders

Comment: We have tried with Sonic and another different encoder, only 3-5ms advantage was found.